# Perl regular expressions and returned array of matched groups

Tags: perl, regex

i am new in Perl and i need to do some regexp.
I read, when array is used like integer value, it gives count of elements inside.

So i am doing for example

```
if (@result = $pattern =~ /(\d)\.(\d)/) {....}
```

and i was thinking it should return empty array, when pattern matching fails, but it gives me still array with 2 elements, but with uninitialized values.

So how i can put pattern matching inside if condition, is it possible?

EDIT:

```
foreach (keys @ARGV) {

    if (my @result = $ARGV[$_] =~ /^--(?:(help|br)|(?:(input|output|format)=(.+)))$/) {

        if (defined $params{$result[0]}) {
            print STDERR "Cmd option error\n";
        }

        $params{$result[0]} = (defined $result[1] ? $result[1] : 1);

    }
    else {
        print STDERR "Cmd option error\n";
        exit ERROR_CMD;
    }

}
```

It is regexp pattern for command line options, cmd options are in long format with two hyphens preceding and possible with argument, so 
--CMD[=ARG]. I want elegant solution, so this is why i want put it to if condition without some prolog etc.

EDIT2: 
oh sry, i was thinking groups in @result array are always counted from 0, but accesible are only groups from branch, where the pattern is success. So if in my code command is "input", it should be in $result[0], but actually it is in $result[1]. I thought if $result[0] is uninitialized, than pattern fails and it goes to the if statement.

Comment: You should provide sample input, and what you expect it to do.

Comment: If the pattern match fails, it will give you the empty list, not two undefined values. Perhaps you should post the code that makes you think that is what happens.

Comment: @LoneShepherd No, the assignment will still happen in list context, it is equal to doing `@result = ...; if (@result)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $pattern = 42.42;

my @result = $pattern =~ /(\d)\.(\d)/;

print @result, ' elements';
```

Output:

```
24 elements
```

Context tells Perl how to treat `@result`.  There certainly aren't 24 elements!  Perl has printed the array's elements which resulted from your regex's captures.  However, if we do the following:

```
print 0 + @result, ' elements';
```

we get:

```
2 elements
```

In this latter case, Perl interprets a scalar context for `@result`, so adds the number of elements to `0`.  This can also be achieved through `scalar @results`.

Edit to accommodate revised posting: Thus, the conditional in your code:

```
if(my @result = $ARGV[$_] =~ /^--(?:(help|br)|(?:(input|output|format)=(.+)))$/) { ...
```

evaluates to `true` if and only if the match was successful.

Answer (score 2):

```
@results = $pattern =~ /(\d)\.(\d)/ ? ($1,$2) : ();
```

Comment: In the fail to match case, the original code returned a list with two elements, both undefined. This returns an empty list.

Comment: No, the original code returned the empty list when the match failed. If it does not match, it doesn't return captured elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@result = ();
if ($pattern =~ /(\d)\.(\d)/)
{
 push @result, $1;
 push @result, $2;
}
```

=~ is not an equal sign. It's doing a regexp comparison.

So my code above is initializing the array to empty, then assigning values only if the regexp matches.